# Is there any way to request a page without displaying it?

Tags: html, http

If you link to something downloadable with a simple `<a href`, the user will download the file while staying on the current page. You can get this behavior with files that the browser has no plugin for (like .bin), or by sending a content-disposition header to force downloading.

Is there any method or header which keeps the user on the current page while still requesting the page? The idea is that the user clicks a link, the request is made, but the page doesn't change—like when downloading a file.

This could be done with an iframe I guess, which is not really pretty and makes another request when loading the page. Javascript is another obvious answer, but that's actually the reason for asking this question: compatibility with JS-less clients.

A form with the method set to HEAD is another ugly solution, but doesn't work anyway. Chromium ignores the method and simply performs a GET request...

Anymore ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do? If you want the browsers to present a download dialog to the user, send the correct MIME type

Comment: Is there anything in particular that is required on the user's part to trigger this behavior? Or should it happen automatically on page load? Or something else? And what do you want to happen with the data?

Comment: Hm okay my question is too unclear it seems. Will edit. My purpose is that when a user clicks a link, a page is requested, but the user won't see the page (it'll be blank anyway). Similar to when linking to a downloadable file, the browser will download but not direct the user to that page.

Comment: Do you want to the user to download a file? If not, what's the point in requesting a resource, if the user never gets to see it anyway …

Comment: I still don't understand why you would want to do it.

Comment: One use case would be to effectively implement an Ajax request without using JavaScript.

Comment: The use is to +1 a post without reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place an iframe on your page that is hidden. Then, give that iframe and id.

Use this id as the target of a link to the file you want to pull down.

I've created a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/dancrumb/N87nL/ to show you how this would work. Just style the iframe as being invisible and you're good to go

The page will load in the iframe, you'll stay on your page, it doesn't require JS. Oh boy!

Note that the iFrame doesn't have an initial value for `src`, so no request is made on page load.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that the `target` attribute works on anchors :)